# App dont show in market for tablets

Tags: android, tablet

I've done an app and I've tried it on my tablet via USB. 
But when I uploaded it to market it didnt show for my pad... :S
I guess the problem is in my manifest...

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster.BookInterface"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_book_interface"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster.Peekaboo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_peekaboo"
            android:parentActivityName="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster.MainActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.thorne.godnattsmamonster.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What do I need to add? 
BR

Answer (score 1):

`android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`

That's your problem there. Some/most tablets don't have external storage. Either use internal storage (in which case you don't need a permission), or try adding `android:required="false"` to your WRITE_EXTERAL_STORAGE permission. Either way though, you are going to have to go into your code where you are writing to external storage and change it to internal, or handle the case where a tablet doesn't have external storage.

Comment: For newer Nexus this helped. But for the older once with tvdpi it didnt improve.

Comment: Do those tablets have cameras? If not, you'll need to make the CAMERA permission required="false" as well. And possibly VIBRATE.

Comment: Set all to false and also added: <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />